# Wamp64 not persisting session between pages, each page change generates a new session

Tags: session, configuration, wampserver

A reinstall of Wamp64Server3.1.0_x64 is running on a Windows 10 Pro 10.0.18362 Build 18362 64-bit Dell workstation at c:\wamp64 via LocalHost as a closed php development environment.

All php.ini files in c:\wamp64 and below have the following session variable settings.  In this development environment, we want session variables to be stored in the c:\wamp\tmp folder as SESS_ files, not in cookies.

```
[Session]
session.save_handler = files
session.save_path ="c:\wamp64\tmp" 
;(Note: if this is specified as c:/wamp64/tmp, Apache generates "can't find folder" errors.)
session.use_strict_mode = 0
session.use_cookies = 0 
;(Note: Presumably setting use_cookies to 0 causes all cookie-related variables to be ignored.)
session.use_only_cookies = 0
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.cookie_path = /
session.cookie_domain =
session.cookie_httponly =
session.serialize_handler = php
session.gc_probability = 1
session.gc_divisor = 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.referer_check =
session.cache_limiter = nocache
session.cache_expire = 180
session.use_trans_sid = 0
session.hash_function = 0
session.hash_bits_per_character = 5
url_rewriter.tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry"
```

Two php files, test1.php and test2.php, are in the c:\wamp64\www\testsession folder:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Session Test Page 1</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
 echo session_id().'<br>'; print_r($_SESSION); echo '<br>';
$_SESSION['page'] = 'Page 1';
echo session_id().'<br>'; print_r($_SESSION); echo '<br>';
?>
<form action="page2.php">
                <input type="submit" value="Page 2">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Session Test Page 2</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
 echo session_id().'<br>'; print_r($_SESSION); echo '<br>';
$_SESSION['page'] = 'Page 2';
echo session_id().'<br>'; print_r($_SESSION); echo '<br>';
?>
<form action="page1.php">
                <input type="submit" value="Page 1">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

To access Page 1, a browser is opened and a URL of "localhost/testsession/page1.php is entered, resulting immediately in a sess_7dmdo58tq30mh2bf7712vecrk2 file in c:\wamp64\tmp and display of the page in the browser.  The session_id and the entire contents of the $_SESSION array are displayed, a $_SESSION variable "page" is set, and the session_id and $_SESSION array are displayed again. The output looks like this:

```
7dmdo58tq30mh2bf7712vecrk2

Array ( )

7dmdo58tq30mh2bf7712vecrk2

Array ( [page] => Page 1 )
```

When the Page 2 submit button is clicked, a sess_bbf1umlcfkhr6cbf5038isqev4 file is created immediately in c:\wamp64\tmp, and the following output appears on the screen in the same browser tab (a separate tab is not opened):

```
bbf1umlcfkhr6cbf5038isqev4

Array ( )

bbf1umlcfkhr6cbf5038isqev4

Array ( [page] => Page 2 )
```

Note that the session_id when the second page is displayed is different from the first page's session_id and the $*SESSION array is initially empty when it should have Array ( [page] => Page 1 ) passed to it.  Obviously the array is empty because the second page is running a different session than the first page.  In other words, the first page's session is not persisted to the second page. The sess* files contain the set `$_SESSION['page']` value, assuming the submit button has been clicked on both pages.

This same behavior occurs in multiple browsers: Chrome, Edge, Internet Explorer, Firefox, Avast Secure Browser.

As you can see from the code above, `<?php session_start(); ?>` has been used religiously in both php files as the very first line.  I've searched through endless forum posts that insist that leaving this out or misplacing it is the problem.  In only one such post, the solution was for the hosting service's support team to make a configuration change, but the next comment said simply, "It would be nice to know what they changed." Indeed!!

Because this problem is browser-independent, follows on the heels of a reinstall of Wamp64, and the php code is so straightforward, I'm convinced it's a configuration problem in either the php module or the Apache module of Wamp.  But I can find no references to any setting that might cause this behavior.  No previous installations of Wamp (and I've used many, both in a localhost development environment and on live websites) has ever exhibited this problem.  I'm reluctant to uninstall WampServer and reinstall it again unless absolutely necessary due to the need to track down scattered php.ini and other config files in the installation - again - to make sure many settings are right for my environment.  Thankfully this is not happening with a live website.

I suspect it's a configuration issue in either php or Apache.  I'm stumped.  Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The above pages can be viewed in a live website at https://shoshonebch.org/codetest/page1.php where they behave as expected.

Comment: The Wamp64Server3.1.0_x64 package contains three versions of PHP, 5.6.31, 7.0.23, and 7.1.9.  The default version on installation is 5.6.31.  Switching to 7.1.9 resolved the problem.  (This back version of Wamp64Server was needed to restore the original development environment for the website in question.)

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is a result of using the installation's default PHP version, 5.6.31.  Switch to version 7.1.9 by opening the management pop-up, hover over the PHP option, then over the Version option, and then click the 7.1.9 option.  The server will do an auto-restart when the change is made.